# Vista BEX error

Tags: winapi, windows-vista

Recently I got IE7 crashed on Vista on jar loading (presumably) with the following error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:        BEX
  Application Name:          iexplore.exe
  Application Version:       7.0.6001.18000
  Application Timestamp:     47918f11
  Fault Module Name:         ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version:      6.0.6001.18000
  Fault Module Timestamp:    4791a7a6
  Exception Offset:          00087ba6
  Exception Code:            c000000d
  Exception Data:            00000000
  OS Version:                6.0.6001.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:                 1037
  Additional Information 1:  fd00
  Additional Information 2:  ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
  Additional Information 3:  fd00
  Additional Information 4:  ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
```

Googling revealed this sort of problems [is](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1194672&SiteID=1) [common](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=eu&comments_parentId=101420&forumId=1) [for](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29930817/bex-problem.aspx) [Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.vc.mfc&tid=d511c635-3c99-431d-8118-526d3e3fff00&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) and relates to [Java](http://www.gomanuals.com/java_not_working_on_windows_vista.shtml) (although SUN [negates](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/chet/archive/2006/10/java_on_vista_y.html)). Also I think it has something to do with DEP. I failed to find official Microsoft Kb.

So, the questions are:

- What BEX stands for?
- What is it about?
- How to deal with such kind of errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BEX=Buffer overflow exception. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483.aspx for details. However, c000000d is STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER; the technet article talks primarily about status c0000005 or c0000409 (access violation/DEP)

Answer (score 2):

Java and IE7 do not like to play together nicely.  Just turn off DEP, it will work fine then.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1261/vista_disable_dep_noexecute_protection_fix_explorer_crashing/

Answer (score 1):

go to internet explorer options/ advanced /security/ uncheck the box that says enable memory protection to mitigate attacks this will work it did for me

go to internet explorer options/ advanced /security/ uncheck the box that says enable memory protection to mitigate attacks this will work it did for me

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is an addon that is messing with IE.

You can try this.
1.      Open IE
2.      Switch to the Advanced tab.
3.      Click the Reset Internet Explorer Settings button.
4.      Click Reset to confirm the operation.
5.      Click Close when the resetting process finished.
6.      Uncheck Enable third-party browser extensions option in the Settings box.
7.      Click Apply, click OK.

After this, check to see if it works and if it does, enable one addon at a time until you find the culprit. Then uninstall it and reinstall it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

just try disabling the bing or msn toolbar - should do the trick.